# AWS Managed Prometheus Alert Manager unable to (easily) silence alerts using Grafana

Tags: amazon-web-services, prometheus-alertmanager, grafana-alerts

I'm using AWS Managed Prometheus workspaces with Grafana version 9.3
I've used sigv4 and setup Grafana for both the AMP Datasource, and the AMP Alert Manager Data source.

I can see my AMP alert manager alarms created by terraform in Grafana, I can also see & create Grafana Managed Alerts directly inside Grafana.

I've noticed that when I use Grafana Managed Alerts (which I assume run on the Grafana node itself, rather than on the cloud).  Grafana Managed Alerts can *easily* and *painlessly* convert an alarm into a silence. There is a simple button in "view alarm" which copies the labels into the field, and the operator can quickly add/delete labels to a suitable silence rule.

I've noticed the same functionality doesn't exist with AWS Managed Prometheus Alert Manager Alarms.  The operator can create a silence (and it seems to work), but the operator can't do it "easily" by quickly copying the fire alarm fields into the silence.
The "Silence" action doesn't appear in Grafana.

I found this guide:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/grafana/latest/userguide/alert-silences.html

It describes how to create a matchers query parameter, but honestly the documentation is pretty ambiguous to me. Not even sure where/how this would be configured.

Comment: A bit more investigation suggests this is a bug on AWS, or a "feature" not implemented in Grafana OSS:
https://github.com/grafana/grafana/issues/60135

Answer (score 0):

Figured out why my issue was occurring, probably won't happen to anybody else since it was related to my 8.x Grafana config.

https://github.com/grafana/grafana/issues/60135

Answer (score 0):

Adding data source correctly using below reference
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/grafana/latest/userguide/data-source-alertmanager.html

And adding the IAM permission

Comment: Please post the essentials here, link only answers tend to get deleted.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).